# How long for forecast::auto.arima to work?

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I am working through some [demo code](https://github.com/Sasidhar-Sirivella/Energy-Consumption-Forecasting---Multiple-Seasonality/blob/master/RCode_Energy%20Consumption.R) that accompanied a [medium post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/forecasting-time-series-with-multiple-seasonal-patterns-in-r-9ecaf1b685d2) on high frequency time series forecasting using the `forecast::auto.arima` function. Whether in this application or when I have tried other datasets, I have never been able to get a result from this function - it does seem to stop calculating once I have executed it. Others have, obviously; so I'm asking how long you need to wait to get a result from the function.

#### Example

[Data on hourly energy use can be downloaded](https://www.kaggle.com/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption?select=DUQ_hourly.csv) from Kaggle.

Using that data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)

duq_pc <- read.csv(file.choose(),stringsAsFactors = F)

duq_new <- duq_pc[duq_pc$Datetime >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' & duq_pc$Datetime <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00',]

duq_train <- duq_new[duq_new$Datetime <= '2016-12-31',]
duq_test <- duq_new[duq_new$Datetime >= '2017-01-01',]
msts_power <- msts(duq_train$DUQ_MW, seasonal.periods = c(24,24*7,24*365.25), start = decimal_date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:00:00")))

#Dynamic Harmonic regression with Auto Arima

fourier_power <- auto.arima(msts_power, seasonal=FALSE, lambda=0,
                            xreg=fourier(msts_power, K=c(10,10,10)))
```

Very interested to hear whether this is something that I would need to leave running overnight or whether other people are getting results in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running your code and measuring the times in between, it took about 40 minutes to finish. For what it's worth, I launched the script on a computer with an AMD Ryzen 2700 Eight-Core Processor 3.20 GHZ, 16 GB of RAM.

[image: Evidence]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the size of your dataset and your computer specs. You can use the `tictoc` library for an easy way to record time, and set `trace = TRUE` in your `auto.arima` call to output its progress to console.

```
library(tictoc)

tic()
fourier_power <- auto.arima(msts_power, seasonal=FALSE, lambda=0,    trace = TRUE
                            xreg=fourier(msts_power, K=c(10,10,10)))
toc()
```